# Enumerate_it gem strange code in class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I stumbled on strange code in [enumerate_it](https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it) gem:

```
module EnumerateIt
  module ClassMethods
    def has_enumeration_for(attribute, options = {})
      self.enumerations = self.enumerations.dup
      ...
    end
end
```

It seems senseless for me, but I sure gem developers had reasons to write this.
What is the reason to use assignment like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oooh, code archeology! Luckily, this is an open source project, so we have access to the history of the code, and - hopefully - the reasons for changes (as described in commit messages).

The code in question:

```
self.enumerations = self.enumerations.dup
```

was originally added in [commit 04bec59407bf14d3ab219c4b505ef1fbfce0c398](https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it/commit/04bec59407bf14d3ab219c4b505ef1fbfce0c398), which has a pretty good commit message that explains why it was added:

> #### Respect superclass enumerations on subclasses
>
> Previously, this was the behavior:
>
> ```
> class Unico::Person
>   has_enumeration_for :gender
> end
>
> class Person < Unico::Person
> end
>
> Unico::Person.enumerations
> # => {:gender => Gender}
>
> Person.enumerations
> # => {}
> ```
>
> After this commit, subclasses will inherit the superclass enumerations:
>
> ```
> class Unico::Person
>   has_enumeration_for :gender
> end
>
> class Person < Unico::Person
> end
>
> Unico::Person.enumerations
> # => {:gender => Gender}
>
> Person.enumerations
> # => {:gender => Gender}
> ```

#### How to find that

Check out a copy of the repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it.git
Cloning into 'enumerate_it'...
remote: Counting objects: 995, done.
remote: Total 995 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 995
Receiving objects: 100% (995/995), 178.90 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (474/474), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd enumerate_it
```

Now, let's find all commits containing the code in question:

```
$ git log -S "self.enumerations = self.enumerations.dup"
commit c99a15c31d156464b1139533d4377331b6e21fff
Author: Cássio Marques <cassio.marques@baby.com.br>
Date:   Thu Nov 8 17:16:36 2012 -0200

    We should extend the EnumerateIt module instead of including it, since the has_enumeration_for is a class method

commit 04bec59407bf14d3ab219c4b505ef1fbfce0c398
Author: Gabriel Sobrinho <gabriel.sobrinho@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu May 31 11:08:57 2012 -0300

    Respect superclass enumerations on subclasses

    Previously, this was the behavior:

      class Unico::Person
        has_enumeration_for :gender
      end

      class Person < Unico::Person
      end

      Unico::Person.enumerations
      # => {:gender => Gender}

      Person.enumerations
      # => {}

    After this commit, subclasses will inherit the superclass enumerations:

      class Unico::Person
        has_enumeration_for :gender
      end

      class Person < Unico::Person
      end

      Unico::Person.enumerations
      # => {:gender => Gender}

      Person.enumerations
      # => {:gender => Gender}
```

Looking closer at the commits with `git show` reveals that the topmost one was simply moving the code from one place to another, while the latter commit actually added the code.

And that's the commit we wanted.

Comment: @Jacob, can you say how you found this commit?

Comment: @Ilya Sure, I've updated the answer with more details.